# Snappy Daemon - snapd on Ubuntu General Question

Tags: server

I've found more pages about the command line options than an overview of the program itself, how does snapd compare to FreeBSD jails or the MacOS process isolation system that doesn't appear to have a name of its own?

Thanks.

@FrysAcidTest